# Expose filtering to users of a joined report

Tags: reporting

Is it possible to expose the filters on a joined report to the end user without forcing them to customize the report? My use case calls for the someone to be able to filter by a date field on each of the blocks. I can see and customize the filters all I want when I am editing the report but not on the screen where I would actually run the report.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your user case, you can use "Time Frame" filter on the report to filter data based on date.